# Prove that $S = \{ f\in\textsf{C}([-1,1]) :\, f(-x)=-f(x) \textrm{ for all } x\in [-1,1] \}$ is a subspace of $\textsf{C}([-1,1])$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Let $S = \{ f\in\textsf{C}([-1,1]) :\, f(-x)=-f(x) \textrm{ for all } x\in [-1,1] \}$. Prove that $S$ is a subspace of $\textsf{C}([-1,1])$.

My question: Am I approaching this correctly? My attempt is in the picture below. Thank you guys ahead of time for any help!

---

[image: my attempt]

Comment: $(f+g)(-1)=-2$ does not show that this is not closed under addition.

Comment: really? i thought if the result is not in the set, than it is not closed...?

Comment: To show that it is not in the set you need to prove that $(f+g)(-1) \neq -(f+g)(1)$. But $$-(f+g)(1)=-f(1)-g(1)=f(-1)+g(-1)=-2$$

Comment: ohhhkay. so do i not have to show closure under addition and scalar multiplication? is it safe to say it is in the set because the definition{f(-x)=-f(x)} holds?

Comment: Look, when exercise explicitly tells you to prove something, try to prove it :D. You'll save yourself a lot of time. There are couple of things you've written that are wrong. Why would $f(-1)=-1$ and $g(-1)=-1$? Why do you think that $(f+g)(-1)$ doesn't belong to $[-1,1]$ implies that $f+g$ isn't in $S$?

Comment: Write down what a certain subset $U$ in vector space $V$ needs to satisfy in order to be a subspace. Then try to apply that to this particular case. I don't wanna give you the answer immediately because exercise is not difficult, but it seems you kinda lost track of what you need to prove.

Comment: Why do you assume that $f(-1)=-1$ and $g(-1)=-1$?  This is not what the definition means.

Comment: yea i now realized that i scuffed that. f(-x)=-f(x) is confusing me for some reason. I dont know how to test (f+g)(−1)≠−(f+g)(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your first error has to do with understanding what $C([-1,1])$ means.  The $[-1,1]$ is the domain of the function.  What your work is showing is that
$$
\{f\in C([-1,1]):f(-1)=-1\}
$$
is not a subspace of $C([-1,1])$ since it is not closed under addition.  The problem is that the assumption that $f(-1)=-1$ is not part of the given information.  In fact, there are many odd continuous functions like $f(x)=\sin(x)$ which do not satisfy these conditions.

The definition
$$
\{f\in C([-1,1]):f(-x)=-f(x)\text{ for all }x\in[-1,1]\}
$$
means that the domain of the functions is $[-1,1]$, the functions are continuous, and they satisfy $f(-x)=-f(x)$, i.e., they are odd functions.  There are many odd functions such that $f(-1)\not=-1$.

What you should prove:

1. The set is not empty.  Does the $0$ function satisfy the conditions?  Is it continuous on $[-1,1]$?  Does $0(-x)=-0(x)$?
2. The set is closed under addition.  If you have two functions in the set $f$ and $g$, is $f+g$ in the set?  In other words, is $f+g$ continuous with domain $[-1,1]$?  Is $(f+g)(-x)=-(f+g)(x)$?
3. The set is closed under scaling.  If you have the function $f$ in the set and $c$ is a scalar, is $cf$ in the set?  In other words, is $cf$ continuous with domain $[-1,1]$?  Is $(cf)(-x)=-(cf)(x)$?

As an example, to show that $(f+g)(-x)=-(f+g)(x)$, we consider the following: Starting with $(f+g)(-x)=f(-x)+g(-x)$, we use the odd property of $f$ and $g$ (since they're in the set) to get $f(-x)+g(-x)=-f(x)-g(x)$.  But this is $-(f(x)+g(x))=-((f+g)(x))=-(f+g)(x)$.

Comment: first off. thank you. secondly, 
1. yes
2. yes
3. yes
so S is a subspace of C then?

Comment: Well, the question asked you to prove that it was a subspace, so, unless the question is wrong, yes, it's a subspace.